# 3D printed object can't print straight upward

Tags: 3d-models, diy-3d-printer, troubleshooting

I have a weird problem, my object base starts good and then as the object goes to the next layers it is off centered. I have a picture to better explain.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Layer shift is the keyword you should use to find existing info on this kind of problem.

Comment: This is classic layer shift. There are lots of possible causes, but I would check for over-tight belts first.